# Debugging a debug C++ COM dll with pdb but without source code

Tags: c++, dll, atl, pdb-files, atlcom

I am receiving crash while i run the application in (say Connection.dll)

Prior to crash the following assertion comes in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h  on line no: 4735(see below)

ATLASSERT(pdispparams->cArgs == (UINT)info.nParams);

Now client has supplied pdb file of the Connection.dll.

But client has not provided the source code of Connection.dll.

I want to find out the root cause(function name atleast in the Connection.dll) giving the issue.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandip Pawar

Comment: A PDB file maps from position in binary file to position in source file. I don't think it will do you much good without the source files.

Comment: The root cause is pretty simple to see, you are calling a method with the wrong number of arguments.  That never comes to a good end.  You need to update your MFC wrapper from the new type library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get VisualStudio to load the PDB it will show you the function names, stack and parameters so that'll give you some clues. Putting the PDB alongside the DLL may work, or you may need to add it to the symbol path. If the PDB doesn't exactly match the version of the DLL it usually refuses to load it, which is a PITA.